# Can we change in method signature which will work for previous signature in Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis

I have a webservice with signature
public String `m1(String s1, String s2)` and I wanted to update this signature to public String `m1(String s1, String s2, Object... args)`. Will it work for client calling `m1(String s1, String s2)`? Will it be a backword compatible?

I tried calling but it is throwing an exception as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: SampleService.m1(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at TestWsClient.main(TestWsClient.java:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Create a new method, and deprecate the old one. Make sure you update the documentation to reflect this, so people writing new applications will not use the old one accidentally.